# I'm not able to import any flutter's packages on Android Studio

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

**Issues**

[image]

**Dart Analysis**

[image]

And the contain of my *pubspec.yaml*

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve this please ? anyone can help me please ???

**Flutter Doctor**

[image]

**Flutter Doctor -v**

[image]

Comment: have you run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: @RisheekMittal yes

Comment: Can you show me your `flutter doctor`?

Comment: inside my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could **delete** all your **Pods**, use **flutter clean** and then a **flutter pub get**.

Comment: same problem sr